# Volume of the convex hull of the set of all graphic sequences of a given length

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, degree-sequence

Consider the set of all graphic sequences with $n$ elements as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, namely let
$$D(n)=\{(d_{1},\dots,d_{n})\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}^{n}:d_{1}\geq\dots\geq d_{n},\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}\ \text{is even},\ \sum_{i=1}^{k}d_{i}\leq k(k-1)+\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\min\{k,d_{i}\}\ \text{for all}\ 1\leq k\leq n \}.$$
One can observe that the diameter of $D(n)$ equals $(n-1)\sqrt[]{n}$. The question is:

> How to compute the volume of the convex hull of $D(n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polytope considered by Richard Stanley is the polytope of degree sequences.
Sergiy Kozerenko's question is about the polytope of degree partitions for which see paper R46 of Volume 13 (2006) of the Electronic Journal of combinatorics. It is shown there that the volume of the polytope of degree sequences is n! times the volume of the polytope of degree partitions.

Comment: Thanks for this observation. When I said that the question of Kozerenko seems to be much more difficult, I was actually thinking of the number of integer points, not the volume.

Answer (score 4):

This is worked out in section 3 of Stanley's paper ["A Zonotope Associated with Graphical Degree Sequences"](http://dedekind.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/83.pdf). The answer is $$\operatorname{Vol}(D(n))=\sum_{X}2^{c(X)}$$
where $X$ ranges through all graphs whose connected components contain a unique cycle, which is of odd length, and $c(X)$ is the number of odd cycles.

Comment: Actually, I compute the volume of the convex hull of all *ordered* degree sequences of length $n$, that is, I don't assume $d_1\leq d_2\leq \cdots \leq d_n$. The question of Kozerenko is completely different and seems to be much more difficult.